# How get height of title screen on blackberry screen?

Tags: blackberry, screen, field, title

Why getHeight after setTitle equal null? 
How do I get the actual height value?

```
public class ActivityScreen extends MainScreen {
    /**
     * Creates new instance Activity screen
     */
    public ActivityScreen() {
      super();
          TitleFieldManager titleField = new TitleFieldManager(Display.getWidth());
          super.setTitle(titleField);
          if (titleField.getHeight() == 0) {
             // Why titleField.getHeight() == 0 ?
          }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are calling `titleField.getHeight()` in the screen's constructor. At this point the UI framework has not passed the layouting/measuring process for the screen yet. If for instance, you will call the same `titleField.getHeight()` after at least one screen's  `paint(Graphics graphics)` call has been executed you'll be able to get a non-zero value. All layouting/measuring is guaranteedly passed BEFORE the screen content can be drawn.

Check the [Manager.sublayout(int width, int height) API](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/6022/net/rim/device/api/ui/Manager.html#sublayout%28int,%20int%29). `MainScreen` is also a `Manager`. So at some point AFTER the screen has been constructed, but BEFORE it is painted, the UI framework calls its `sublayout(int width, int height)` where all layouting/measuring happens (all child fields get their sizes).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of this, but I think the height of the element is calculated when the manager that contains it is laid out.

Try pushing the screen that contains that title and then calling `titleField.getHeight()`